# Can't install Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I can't install ionic on window. I see this error message.

> npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\EUNOVA~2\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4944-a5
>        4758ba\registry.npmjs.org\cordova-js-\cordova-js-4.0.0.tgz
>        npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\EUNOVA~2\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4944-a5
>        4758ba\registry.npmjs.org\npm-\npm-1.3.4.tgz

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi the same issue here, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315884/npm-install-untar-error

Answer (score 1):

Solution worked for me

Follow the steps

1. Install all necessary dependencies.
   http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html
2. Uninstall node.js from PC if already installed
3. Restart PC
4. Download and Install node.js (MSI Installer) from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/ for x86 or http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/ for x64
5. Right-click Command prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
6. Install Cordova using the command: npm install -g cordova
7. Finally install Ionic Framework using the command: npm install -g ionic
8. Reinstall node.js http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/ for x86 or http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/x64/ for x64

Done!